# Inject IServiceProvider using ServiceProvider into SignInManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I've made some research, and there isn't much info about registering standard classes for manual DI. Experiencing lots of issues trying to implement unit tests in asp net core 2.1 app, here is the last one. Getting null refrence exception when trying to SignInAsync user created by UserManager - it seems it can't inject IServiceProvider instance

```
var userManager = Resolve<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
await signInManager.SignInAsync(userManager.FindByIdAsync(adminId), false); // here
```

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: provider 
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.SignInAsync(TUser user, AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties, String authenticationMethod)
>      at UnitTests.TestBase`1.ConfigureIdentity() in C:\Users\alexa\source\repos\octopusstore\UnitTests\TestBase.cs:line 72

resolving like this

```
protected static ServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
protected T Resolve<T>()
{
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    return serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();
}
```

how I am registering dependencies, it worked so far

```
services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>();
var conf = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(conf.Object);
services.AddSingleton<IServiceProvider, ServiceProvider>() ; // except for this
services.AddSingleton(services.BuildServiceProvider()); // and this
services.AddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>> ();
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>()
       .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationService, DefaultAuthorizationService> ();
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider>();
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandlerProvider, DefaultAuthorizationHandlerProvider>();
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandlerContextFactory, DefaultAuthorizationHandlerContextFactory>();
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationEvaluator, DefaultAuthorizationEvaluator>();
```

interesting that UserManager worked fine

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). A [mcve] should help clarify the actual problem

Comment: @Nkosi I understand what you ask for, but really can't provide more code: it just happens in SignInAsync and that's all

Comment: Then you need to clarify the current question as it is unclear what problem you are trying to describe.

Comment: @Nkosi I added some info I understood

Comment: I guess there is some low-level magic inserting it in asp net core project, that isn't available in XUnit project.

Comment: Did you try to resolve it using a Scope ?

Comment: @aguafrommars I did, no avail

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] and show the test code necessary to reproduce this?

Answer (score 10):

To register the service provider itself, you can do it like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IServiceProvider>(sp => sp);
```

This uses the factory function which you can use to get an instance using the service provider `sp`. Since you want to register the service provider itself, you can just return `sp` directly.